# Restrict WSGI based on IP

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost, mod-wsgi, whitelist

So I have trac running on my debian server with the VirtualHost file looking like:

```
...
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/domain/trac.wsgi
WSGIScriptReloading On

<Directory /srv/domain/tracprojects>
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
...
```

I thought this might deny access to everyone (which I wanted to do to test that this would work). Unfortunatley this didn't affect the setup although the trac application still runs.

Is there something I need to put in my wsgi file to restrict access instead of in my virtual host file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have used:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/domain/trac.wsgi

<Directory /srv/domain/>
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

That may stop other stuff as well below that directory though, so use instead:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/domain/trac.wsgi

<Directory /srv/domain/tracprojects>
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  Order deny,allow
  <Files trac.wsgi>
  Deny from all
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

BTW, you don't need WSGIScriptReloading.

Also make sure you read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Using daemon mode would be prefered.

General setup instructions for Trac at:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithTrac

Comment: Hi thanks, sorry the WSGIScriptReloading was a throwback from my flask setup (I copied the virtualhost file...), anyway I've removed that now.